# how do I alias Minitest spec methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias, minitest

I'm using Minitest spec in a rails project and I want to use `must` as an alias for `must_be` and `wont` as an alias for `wont_be`

in April 2015 Chris Kottom gave [an example](http://chriskottom.com/blog/2015/04/unexpected-the-new-minitest-spec-syntax/) of this by doing this:

```
module Minitest::Expectations
  alias_method :must, :must_be
end
```

But when I try the same it doesn't work. I put that code before my test class and this test:

```
it 'uses the alias' do
  user = User.take
  _(user).must(:valid?)
end
```

gives this error:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?' for #<Minitest::Expectation:0x0055b830595608>
```

(when I change `must` to `must_be` the test passes)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you don't use `must_be`?

Comment: I'd rather type `_(my_mock).must :verify` than `_(my_mock).must_be :verify`